# what should I do if my regression model stuck at a high value loss?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, regression, pytorch, skorch

I'm using neural nets for a regression problem where I have 3 features and I'm trying to predict one continuous value. I noticed that my neural net start learning good but after 10 epochs it get stuck on a high loss value and could not improve anymore.

- I tried to use Adam and other adaptive optimizers instead of SGD but that didn't work. I tried a complex architectures like adding layers, neurons, batch normalization and other activations etc.. and that also didn't work.
- I tried to debug and try to find out if something is wrong with the implementation but when I use only 10 examples of the data my model learn fast so there are no errors.  I start to increase the examples of the data and monitoring my model results as I increase the data examples. when I reach 3000 data examples my model start to get stuck on a high value loss.
- I tried to increase layers, neurons and also to try other activations, batch normalization. My data are also normalized between [-1, 1], my target value is not normalized since it is regression and I'm predicting a continuous value. I also tried using keras but I've got the same result.

My real dataset have 40000 data, I don't know what should I try, I almost try all things that I know for optimization but none of them worked. I would appreciate it if someone can guide me on this. I'll post my Code but maybe it is too messy to try to understand, I'm sure there is no problem with my implementation, I'm using skorch/pytorch and some SKlearn functions:

```
# take all features as an Independant variable except the bearing and distance
# here when I start small the model learn good but from 3000 data points as you can see the model stuck on a high value. I mean the start loss is 15 and it start to learn good but when it reach 9 it stucks there
# and if I try to use the whole dataset for training then the loss start at 47 and start decreasing until it reach 36 and then stucks there too
X = dataset.iloc[:3000, 0:-2].reset_index(drop=True).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)

# take distance and bearing as the output values:
y = dataset.iloc[:3000, -2:].reset_index(drop=True).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)
y_bearing = y[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
y_distance = y[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1)

# normalize the input values
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_norm = scaler.fit_transform(X, y)

X_br_train, X_br_test, y_br_train, y_br_test = train_test_split(X_norm,
                                                                y_bearing,
                                                                test_size=0.1,
                                                                random_state=42,
                                                                shuffle=True)

X_dis_train, X_dis_test, y_dis_train, y_dis_test = train_test_split(X_norm,
                                                                    y_distance,
                                                                    test_size=0.1,
                                                                    random_state=42,
                                                                    shuffle=True)
bearing_trainset = Dataset(X_br_train, y_br_train)
bearing_testset = Dataset(X_br_test, y_br_test)

distance_trainset = Dataset(X_dis_train, y_dis_train)
distance_testset = Dataset(X_dis_test, y_dis_test)


def root_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))


class RMSELoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mse = nn.MSELoss()

    def forward(self, yhat, y):
        return torch.sqrt(self.mse(yhat, y))


class AED(nn.Module):
    """custom average euclidean distance loss"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, yhat, y):
        return torch.dist(yhat, y)


def train(on_target,
          hidden_units,
          batch_size,
          epochs,
          optimizer,
          lr,
          regularisation_factor,
          train_shuffle):

    network = None
    trainset = distance_trainset if on_target.lower() == 'distance' else bearing_trainset
    testset = distance_testset if on_target.lower() == 'distance' else bearing_testset
    print(f"shape of trainset.X = {trainset.X.shape}, shape of trainset.y = {trainset.y.shape}")
    print(f"shape of testset.X = {testset.X.shape}, shape of testset.y = {testset.y.shape}")

    mse = EpochScoring(scoring=mean_squared_error, lower_is_better=True, name='MSE')
    r2 = EpochScoring(scoring=r2_score, lower_is_better=False, name='R2')
    rmse = EpochScoring(scoring=make_scorer(root_mse), lower_is_better=True, name='RMSE')

    checkpoint = Checkpoint(dirname=f'results/{on_target}/checkpoints')
    train_end_checkpoint = TrainEndCheckpoint(dirname=f'results/{on_target}/checkpoints')

    if on_target.lower() == 'bearing':
        network = BearingNetwork(n_features=X_norm.shape[1],
                                 n_hidden=hidden_units,
                                 n_out=y_distance.shape[1])

    elif on_target.lower() == 'distance':
        network = DistanceNetwork(n_features=X_norm.shape[1],
                                  n_hidden=hidden_units,
                                  n_out=1)

    model = NeuralNetRegressor(
        module=network,
        criterion=RMSELoss,
        device='cpu',
        batch_size=batch_size,
        lr=lr,
        optimizer=optim.Adam if optimizer.lower() == 'adam' else optim.SGD,
        optimizer__weight_decay=regularisation_factor,
        max_epochs=epochs,
        iterator_train__shuffle=train_shuffle,

        train_split=predefined_split(testset),
        callbacks=[mse, r2, rmse, checkpoint, train_end_checkpoint]
    )

    print(f"{'*' * 10} start training the {on_target} model {'*' * 10}")
    history = model.fit(trainset, y=None)

    print(f"{'*' * 10} End Training the {on_target} Model {'*' * 10}")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = parser.parse_args()

    train(on_target=args.on_target,
          hidden_units=args.hidden_units,
          batch_size=args.batch_size,
          epochs=args.epochs,
          optimizer=args.optimizer,
          lr=args.learning_rate,
          regularisation_factor=args.regularisation_lambda,
          train_shuffle=args.shuffle)
```

and this is my network declaration:

```
class DistanceNetwork(nn.Module):
    """separate NN for predicting distance"""
    def __init__(self, n_features=5, n_hidden=16, n_out=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(n_features, n_hidden),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(n_hidden, 5),
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Linear(5, n_out)
        )
```

here is the log while training:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying your loss does not decrease anymore? Or is it increasing after a certain point? Can you show us an excerpt of the training log?

Comment: @nemo it does not decrease anymore. I ll add a log photo of the training and validation loss

Comment: @nemo I added a log, you can see how the loss decrease rapidly in the first epochs but then it stabilize at 6k, it just stuck there and never leave ( well at least I tried 1000 epochs and it stays there)

Comment: It looks like your model is converging and is still slowly decreasing the loss. Have you had difference experiences with simpler models? I'm also not sure why your loss differs that much from the reported rmse values.

Comment: @nemo No the loss actually stay stuck at 6000. my loss is the mean squared error so if you take the square root you ll get the rmse metric that I'm using. It's wierd it never happened to me while doing other projects, I mean 6000 is a very high value of a loss, I ve could understand if it was stuck at 20 or 30 but 6000 is very wierd and I can't say it is stuck at local minimum because I tried different architectures, optimizers, etc.. and it was always like that. I don't know why I get this, I'm sure there is no problem with my code

Comment: Did you somehow find why? And how did you correct it?